# Display apostrophe-widget in apostrophe-page

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have:

- `3d` extending `apostrophe-pieces`
- `3d-pages` extending `apostrophe-pieces-pages` and
- `3d-widgets` extending `apostrophe-widgets`

My `3d-widgets/views/widget.html` is correctly displaying a 3D object.

How can I use that widget when displaying a `3d` object with `3d-pages/views/show.html`?

I do not want to reinvent the wheel and copy `3d-widgets/views/widget.html` to `3d-pages/views/show.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want both your `show.html` and your `widget.html` to make use of a nunjucks macro so that you have an isolated bit of markup that's sole job is to render 3d objects.

You can see that pattern illustrated in the Open Museum when rendering cards that display information about a specific artist.

Here is the macro we will use in other components to render the card. It is just a function that accepts arguments and returns markup. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/master/views/macros/artist-cards.html

Here is the artist index page where we iterate over `pieces` and render cards using the macro
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/f1756c566e46f85f6370a3d1a2c934b342dc7478/lib/modules/artists-pages/views/index.html

And then the Search results page also makes us of the macro to display information about artists returned as part of a search
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum/blob/b2b20a4d7da355c8f448a1442dd17b4a76c2f285/lib/modules/apostrophe-search/views/index.html#L5